# Force acting on valves attached to tires

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

Suppose there is a valve attached to a wheel (tire) as follows:

There is no gravity. The tires rotate clockwise. The distance from the axis of rotation to the valve is **d**, the radius of the tire is **r**, and the angular velocity is constant as **w**.

Now consider a case where the tire decelerates at angular velocity w.

It looks like the valve and the wheel are fully fixed, but **in fact the valve is attached to the wheel like a screw.**

I just want to know **if the valve is tightened or loosened when the wheel itself accelerates or decelerates** in the situation shown. I don't want a calculation.

I'm sorry to ask such a non-specific question. Could I possibly get an answer to this question?

Comment: The axis of rotation is actually on the contact point, and not the center of the wheel, but that does not affect the net torque acting on the valve.

Answer (score 2):

If the valve is attached to the wheel, then when the wheel experiences rotational acceleration/deceleration of $\dot{\omega}$, then the valve must follow suit and also experience the same rotational acceleration/deceleration.

In order to do so, a torque of magnitude $\tau = I_{\rm valve}\,\dot{\omega}$ will be transferred from the wheel to the valve. Here $I_{\rm valve} = \tfrac{1}{8} m_{\rm valve}\, d_{\rm valve}^2$ is the mass moment of inertia of the valve, $m_{\rm valve}$ is the mass of the valve and $d_{\rm valve}$ is the diameter of the valve. I assume the valve axis is parallel to the wheel axis.

The sense of the torque is going to be in the same handiness as the change in rotational motion on the wheel. In your diagram acceleration would mean clock-wise torque and declaration counter-clockwise torque.

Now if the valve is screwed in with a right-hand-screw a counter-clockwise torque would unscrew it.

Comment: If the center of mass of the valve and the center of mass of the wheel are on the same straight line and if they are not (this is the case above), the situation is likely to be different. Intuitively, if the center of mass of the valve and the wheel is on the same line, it is easy to expect that the valve will release as the wheel accelerates or decelerates. In the above case, does torque contribute to the 'spin' of the valve itself even though there is a axis of rotation outside the valve?

Comment: I understand that torque will be exerted by the inertia of the valve if the wheel accelerates and decelerates. But I don't understand how torque contributes to spinning the valve itself. (Isn't it possible to tighten or loosen the valve only when it spins?)

Comment: @NOHWHIREA - Are you concerned about the valve cap unscrewing itself, or the valve body? Regardless a threaded connection, where a torque transfers through it, and this torque exceeds friction it will loosen itself.

Comment: I was just wondering if the torque caused by inertia could cause the valve to spin. It helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Assume the tire is rolling with out slipping on the road, you apply constant torque $~\tau~$ at the center of the tire.

thus the center of the tire angular acceleration is:

$$\alpha_T=  \frac {\tau}{I_T+m_T\,r^2}\\
\omega_T=\alpha\,t$$
$\def \b {\mathbf}$
from here you can obtain the force components $~\mathbf F_v~$ that applied to the valve in coordinate system that fixed at the tire center,
this system is rotating  with $~\omega_T~$

with the position vector of the valve

$$\b P_V=\begin{bmatrix}
    d_x \\
    d_y \\
    0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

and the angular velocity vector

$$\b \omega=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \omega_T \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\b F_V= m_V\,\omega_T^2\begin{bmatrix}
    d_x \\
    d_y \\
    0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$